# Kill all processes linked to a port

Tags: 14.04, kill, killall

Kill all processes on port 3000.
This is what is tried:

```
ubuntu@111:~/chatapp$ sudo netstat -peanut|grep 3000
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          632007      18200/node      
ubuntu@111:~/chatapp$ sudo kill 18200
ubuntu@111:~/chatapp$ sudo netstat -peanut|grep 3000
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          632207      18349/node      
ubuntu@111:~/chatapp$ sudo killall node
ubuntu@111:~/chatapp$ sudo netstat -peanut|grep 3000
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          632364      18414/node      
ubuntu@111:~/chatapp$
```

Comment: There is an open source project I created for this: https://github.com/jkfran/killport

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command to get only `pid`:

```
sudo netstat -peanut | grep 3000 | awk '{ print $9 }' | sed 's:/[^/]*$::' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,5}'
```

`awk` command gets the 9-th field.

`sed` command gets the `pid` before forward slash.

And grep command returns only numbers to eliminate extra lines.

Here you can simply have a loop and kill processes.

Comment: Why does the code mentioned in question does not work?

Comment: Change the code regarding to your case and note that this code only returns process ids and rest of works is up to you.

Comment: The problem I am facing is kill command is not working, not retrieving the PID.

Comment: How do you use `kill` command?

Comment: sudo kill <PID> or sudo killall <name>

Comment: You can do this way: `kill` \`ABOVE_COMMAND\`

Comment: Didn't work. The PID keeps chnaging.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs won't show up unless you run `netstat` with sudo. Compare these two runs :

```
$ netstat -natp | grep tcp6                                                                           
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN 



$ sudo netstat -natp | grep tcp6                                                                      
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1522/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      770/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      770/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1190/sshd
```

As for killing the process linked to a port itself it's a simple case of parsing output from `netstat` (which awk can do) and piping the output from that command to `xargs -I {} kill -TERM  {}`.

Here's how one can parse output with `awk`. By default awk uses spaces to split output into fields, so I do have to loop over all the fields (because of the multiple spaces, awk thinks there's multiple fields in between actual text).

```
$ sudo netstat -natp | awk '/:53579/{sub(/\//," ");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){\                                    
> if($i~/ESTABLISHED/||/LISTEN/||/CLOSE WAIT/) print $(i+1)}}'                                                        
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
5027
```

The rest will be just

```
that_command_above | xargs -I {} kill -TERM  {}
```

Answer (score -1):

**use killport**

killport can be downloaded from here using this:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/master/killport`

`sh killport 3000`

Other way can be using this:

`sudo kill -9 3000`

Comment: `killport` where have you found it ?, `sudo kill -9 3000` - it will kill PID 3000

Comment: It can be downloaded using `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/master/killport`